# Sorting giving weird results while being used with lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I've a really weird problem. I'm working with a panda DataFrame, and while trying to sort the values inside a key, sometimes i get the expected output, and sometimes I don't. Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict


df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ['ID1', 'ID1', "ID1","ID2","ID2"], "pdb" : ["a", "b", "c","d","e"], "beg": [1, 3, 40,111,100], "end" : [11, 12, 50,115,110]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame

for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    df['mew'] = df.apply(lambda x : " ".join(list(map(str,range(x['beg'],x['end']+1)))),axis=1)
    df2 = df.groupby(["ID"], sort=False)['mew']
    .apply(lambda x : (' '.join(x.astype(str)))).reset_index(name='mew')  
    df2['mew'] = (df2['mew'].str.split().apply(lambda x: (OrderedDict.fromkeys(x).keys())).str.join(' '))    
    df2["new"] = (df2["mew"].str.split().apply(lambda x: sorted(x)).str.join(" "))
```

And here's the output that I'm getting:

```
0    1 10 11 12 2 3 4 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49... #This is not sorted at all
1    100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111... #But this is perfectly sorted!
```

vs the one that I should be getting:

```
0    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49...
1    100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 11...
```

I already checked all of the other lines, the problem is with the one sorting the df2["mew"] key, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

The code is kind of messy, so if you have any doubts please ask.

Comment: Are you sorting as a a string or an integer? Given your first example; it is sorted correctly for strings `1 10 11 12 2 3 4 40 41` and your second example is expecting sorting as an integer `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` etc.

Comment: Ohh that might be it, i'm converting to a string in the previous line!